# How to add a fargate profile to an existing cluster with CDK

Tags: amazon-eks, aws-cdk

I want to add a new fargate profile to an existing eks cluster.
The cluster is created in another Stack and in my tenant specific stack I am importing my eks cluster via attributes.

```py
        self.cluster: Cluster = Cluster.from_cluster_attributes(
            self, 'cluster', cluster_name=cluster,
            open_id_connect_provider=eks_open_id_connect_provider,
            kubectl_role_arn=kubectl_role
        )
```

The error is:

```sh
 Object of type @aws-cdk/core.Resource is not convertible to @aws-cdk/aws-eks.Cluster
```

and it is appearing on this line here

```
FargateProfile(self, f"tenant-{self.tenant}", cluster=self.cluster, selectors=[Selector(namespace=self.tenant)])
```

If I try calling

```py
self.cluster.add_fargate_profile(f"tenant-{self.tenant}", selectors=[Selector(namespace=self.tenant)])
```

I get the error that the object self.cluster does not have the attribute `add_fargate_profile`

While you might think that something is of with importing the cluster, adding manifests and helm charts work just fine.

```py
 self.cluster.add_manifest(...) <-- this is working
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not currently possible in CDK.

As per the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-eks.Cluster.html#static-fromwbrclusterwbrattributesscope-id-attrs), `eks.Cluster.fromClusterAttributes` returns an `ICluster`, while `FargateProfile` [expects](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-eks.FargateProfile.html#cluster) a `Cluster` explicitly.

A `FargateCluster` can only currently be created in CDK, not imported.